# What does the acronym OP mean?

Tags: support, status-completed

I feel stupid. On several question there is this comment "It's not what OP ment in her question". OK I know that OP is the one asking the original question - but I have no clue what the acronym is short for.

- OPeartor? Seems wrong
- Other Party? Might be
- Original Poster? Could be...

But which one is the right one? It might not even be anyone of these suggestions... *H E L P*

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Original Poster.

It refers to the person that wrote the post that started the thread.

Comment: On Stack Exchange, "Asker" is really a better term, but OP is more established on forums/ect

Comment: Thanx, my ignorance is gone!

Answer (score 1):

Please also see http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=OP

UrbanDictionary.com is often very useful for explanations of Internet abbreviations.